Equivalence of single/double integral forms of 1D wave equation with a source
My question is about the wave equation on the infinite line with zero initial data and a source $F(x, t)$. I've seen two forms of the solution for this, and I would like to know how they are equivalent.
The first is a double integral over the domain of dependence:
$u(x, t)=\frac{1}{2 c} \int_0^t \int_{x-c(t-\tau)}^{x+c(t-\tau)} F\left(x^{\prime}, \tau\right) d x^{\prime} d \tau$
The second is a single integral, where the inner integral has become just the evaluation at the endpoints (on the characteristic lines):
$u(x, t)=\frac{1}{2 c} \int_0^t[F(x-c(t-\tau), \tau)+F(x+c(t-\tau), \tau)] d \tau$
This second integral is the one that makes sense to me; the final $u(x, t)$ is just a sum (integral) of all the disturbances whose characteristic lines meet at the point $(x, t)$ -- roughly speaking, "two disturbances for each time $\tau \in [0,t]$".
What I do not understand is how this is equivalent to the first form. At first, I thought maybe it was just that the contributions on the interior cancelled out somehow, but of course this can't be the case for arbitrary $F$. I've heard things like "the contributions from the interior are being channeled or funneled to the boundary." or "the contributions from the source term at points within this interval are carried outward to the boundaries, where the characteristics intersect the domain of dependence. This means that, mathematically, we can collapse this spatial integral into evaluations of the source at the boundary points."
These statements help me understand why we could show the equivalence between a double integral form over the domain of dependence and a single integral form over just the boundary. What I don't understand is how they can be equivalent without changing the integrand at all.

The second one is clearly wrong. Just try it out with $F(x,t) \equiv 1$, for example. The first formula gives $u(x,t) = \tfrac12 t^2$ as it should, the second one doesn't. Do you have a source (no pun intended) for the second formula?

Ah, well that would do it - that raises another question for me, but I'll make that another thread. Thanks!
